# Subtract numbers from 2 dataframes based on String in Python

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, pivot, subtraction

I am absolute beginner. Here I have two pivot table stored in two different sheets of same Excel file.

```
df1:
['1C', '1E', '1F', '1H', '1K', '1M', '1N', '1P', '1Q', '1R', '1S', '1U', '1W', '2C', '2E', '2F', '2H', '2K', '2M', '2P', '2S', '2U', '2W']
df2:
['1CA', '1CB', '1CC', '1CF', '1CJ', '1CS', '1CU', '1EA', '1EB', '1EC', '1EF', '1EJ', '1ES', '1FA', '1FB', '1FC', '1FF', '1FJ', '1FS', '1FT', '1FU', '1HA', '1HB', '1HC', '1HF', '1HJ', '1HS', '1HT', '1HU', '1KA', '1KB', '1KC', '1KF', '1KJ', '1KS', '1KU', '1MA', '1MB', '1MC', '1MF', '1MJ', '1MS', '1MU', '1NA', '1NB', '1NC', '1NF', '1NJ', '1PA', '1PB', '1PC', '1PF', '1PJ', '1PS', '1PT', '1PU', '1QA', '1QB', '1QC', '1QF', '1QJ', '1RA', '1RB', '1RC', '1RF', '1RJ', '1SA', '1SB', '1SC', '1SF', '1SJ', '1SS', '1ST', '1SU', '1UA', '1UB', '1UC', '1UF', '1UJ', '1US', '1UU', '1WA', '1WB', '1WC', '1WF', '1WJ', '1WS', '1WU', '2CA', '2CB', '2CC', '2CJ', '2CS', '2EA', '2EB', '2EJ', '2FA', '2FB', '2FC', '2FJ', '2FU', '2HB', '2HC', '2HF', '2HJ', '2HU', '2KA', '2KB', '2KC', '2KF', '2KJ', '2KU', '2MA', '2MB', '2MC', '2MF', '2MJ', '2MS', '2MT', '2PA', '2PB', '2PC', '2PF', '2PJ', '2PU', '2SA', '2SB', '2SC', '2SF', '2SJ', '2UA', '2UB', '2UJ', '2WB', '2WC', '2WF', '2WJ']
```

df2 is sub-categories of df1.

Each sheet has a pivot table:

```
df1:[1 rows x 23 columns]
                1C   1E    1F    1H    1K ...    2M    2P    2S  2U   2W
total          1057  334  3609  3762  1393 ...   328  1611  1426  87  118

df2:[1 rows x 137 columns]
                1CA  1CB  1CC  1CF  1CJ  1CS ...   2UB  2UJ  2WB  2WC  2WF  2WJ
total            11  381  111   20  527    2 ...    47   34   79    2    1   36
```

I want to subtract the value of string ends with `F` in sheet 2. Example: in sheet 2: `1CF`, `1EF`, `1FF` & so on from the respective string i.e `1C`, `1E`, `1F` & so on.

My result should be like `"1C= 1C-1CF= 1037"` and it should be stored in a new sheet (here: Sheet 3).

My Python code:

```
#importing pandas
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from openpyxl import load_workbook
#Assigning the worksheet to file
file="Stratification_worksheet.xlsx"
#Loading the spreadsheet 
data= pd.ExcelFile(file)
#sheetname
print(data.sheet_names)
#loading the sheetname to df1
df=data.parse("Auftrag")
print(df)
# creating tuples
L1=["PMC11","PMP11","PMP21","PMC21","PMP23"]
L2=["PTP33B","PTP31B","PTC31B"]
m1=df["ordercode"].str.startswith(tuple(L1))
m2=df["ordercode"].str.startswith(tuple(L2))
#creating a new column preessurerange and slicing the pressure range from order code
a=df["ordercode"].str.slice(10,12)
b=df["ordercode"].str.slice(11,13)
df["pressurerange"]= np.select([m1,m2],[a,b], default =np.nan)
print(df)
#creating a new coloumn Presssureunit and slicing the preesure unit from ordercode
c=df["ordercode"].str.slice(12,13)
d=df["ordercode"].str.slice(14,15)
df["pressureunit"]= np.select([m1,m2],[c,d], default =np.nan)
print(df)  

#creating a tempcolumn to store pressurerange and pressure unit 
df["pressuresensor"]=df["pressurerange"] + df["pressureunit"]
print(df)

#pivottable 
print(df.pivot_table(values="total",columns="pressurerange",aggfunc={"total":np.sum}))

print(df.pivot_table(values="total",columns="pressuresensor",aggfunc={"total":np.sum}))



#creating new worksheet
df1=df.pivot_table(values="total",columns="pressurerange",aggfunc={"total":np.sum})
df2=df.pivot_table(values="total",columns="pressuresensor",aggfunc={"total":np.sum})


book=load_workbook(file)
writer=pd.ExcelWriter(file,engine="openpyxl")
writer.book = book


df1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="pressurerangepivot")
df2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="pressuresensorpivot")
writer.save()
writer.close()

"""now we have classified the ordercode based on the pressurerange and pressureunit  and we have the sum under each category""" 
#check the columns
print(list(df))
print(list(df1))
print(list(df2))
```

I used `suffix="F"   df3=df1.iloc[:,:]-df2.iloc[:,:].endswith(suffix,1,2)`  But it's showing error:

```
df3=df1['1C']-df2['1CF']
```

this gives exactly value. But I don't know how to do for entire dataframe using simple code.

Comment: When I do this calculation : `1C= 1C-1CF= 1046 `, I get 1057-20=1037? Did I miss something?   Also, can you post images of the two pivot tables, and samples of the underlying data, please. Is python a requirement here ... i.e. if this could be done directly in the workbook, is that an alternative?

Comment: @Jbowman, No u have done correct.

Comment: @Jbowman I'm doing the entire thing using python. That's the requirement. Which data u want exactly??

Comment: @Jbowman Pivot table    `Sheet 1:[1 rows x 23 columns]
pressurerange    1C   1E    1F    1H    1K ...    2M    2P    2S  2U   2W
total          1057  334  3609  3762  1393 ...   328  1611  1426  87  118

Sheet 2:[1 rows x 137 columns]
pressuresensor  1CA  1CB  1CC  1CF  1CJ  1CS ...   2UB  2UJ  2WB  2WC  2WF  2WJ
total            11  381  111   20  527    2 ...    47   34   79    2    1   36`

Comment: I used `suffix="F"   df3=df1.iloc[:,:]-df2.iloc[:,:].endswith(suffix,1,2)`  But its showing error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df2= df2.filter(regex=(".*F$"))  # Leave only 'F' columns in sheet2

df2.columns = [i[:-1] for i in df2.columns]  # Remove 'F' in the end for column-wise subtraction

result = df1 - df2  # Substract values
result[result.isnull()] = sheet1  #leaves when there is no "F"
```